# SVG Animation Issue in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate multiple SVG elements of a logo using CSS animation.

I am using the 'use' method to reference the svg items.

```
<svg class="star" viewBox="0 0 76.349 77.143">
 <use xlink:href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/HEYDAY_star.svg#star"></use>
</svg>
```

The animation works perfectly well in Chrome and Firefox, however in Safari the SVG elements don't display whatsoever.

As an example the animation is applied via css and jquery as below:-

```
.csstransforms .logo-animation #heyday.animate {
   top: -80px;
   animation: top 0.5s ease 1s 1 normal forwards;
   -webkit-animation: top 0.5s ease 1s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

The site is currently visible at: http://heydaymarketing.com.au/staging/

I believe it could be an issue with the 'use' tags? But I am not entirely sure..

Any assistance or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<use>` is not supported in Safari.

Comment: Thanks for the information.. Is there a best practice option for fallbacks? Will 'SVG for Everybody' do the job?

Comment: Each browser will break in its own unique ways, no fixed rule. Only thing left is to report the bug and hope someone will take a stab at it in next release cycle.

Comment: There's already a webkit bug for this (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105904). No need to report it again. You could vote for it though.